# Getting wrong array format using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to pick one random data from JSON array using PHP but the wrong format is coming after getting result. I am explaining the code below.

```
<?php
function array_random_assoc($arr, $num = 1) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    shuffle($keys);

    $r = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $r[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
    }
    return $r;
}
$arr=array(array("id"=>2,"title"=>"hello"),array("id"=>3,"title"=>"hel"),array("id"=>4,"title"=>"hell"),array("id"=>5,"title"=>"helloddd"));
$result=array_random_assoc($arr);
echo json_encode($result);
//print_r(array_random_assoc($arr));
?>
```

Here I am getting the below type result.

```
{"2":{"id":4,"title":"hell"}}
```

Here my requirement is one random set of data will pick from the existing array and the expected output should like below.

```
[{"id":4,"title":"hell"}]
```

for each time of function call the value will be picked randomly from that array.

Comment: put the `print_r($arr)` in your `array_random_assoc()` to see how your array of arrays that you pass as input looks like

Comment: This is absolutely correct. If you fetch a random key and insert into a new array, at `$key` position, your resulting array will have just one position: `$key`. What you want to achieve is just a normal push, so `$r[] = $arr[$keys[$i]];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

then simply replace this line:

```
$r[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
```

with

```
$r[] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
```

You are getting that format because you have assigned key to array, just need to remove that assignment.

Comment: Beaten to it by a few secs :)

Comment: @subhra glad to help you :)